# Is there a way to define what object to create based on a user input?

Tags: java, object

I've developed some code and all my methods use a custom object I created called account. I'm now splitting account into two different types of account, deposit account and savings account. My issue is that all my methods use the original account object, as it stands I'm going to have to have the same methods twice for each different type of account. This seems very inefficient and a bit tedious to change. Ideally I'd want to take a user input savings/deposit and then create the relevant object and use this repeatedly so I don't need to define all the methods twice.  Just as an example here is one of my methods. To summarise I'd want this method to do the exact same thing for both account types just on different objects and the files to be named slightly differently (filname-savings.txt and filenameTransactions-savings.txt)

Is this possible or is there a better way to solve this issue?

```
Account account = new Account();
public void ManageAccount(String name) {

    try {
        File myObj = new File(name + ".txt");

        if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
            File myTransactionObj = new File(name + "Transactions.txt");
            myTransactionObj.createNewFile();
            // If File doesn't exist creates name.txt with 0 balance
            writer.SingleLineWriter(name, "0");
        } else {
            account.setName(name);
            String line = reader.SingleLineRead(name);

            double balance = Double.parseDouble(line);
            double newBalance = ManageBank(balance);

            writer.BalanceAppender(newBalance, name);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

SavingsAccount class

```
public class SavingsAccount extends AbstractBankAccount implements BankAccount {

}
```

DepositAccount class

```
public class DepositAccount extends AbstractBankAccount implements BankAccount {

}
```

Bank Class

```
public class Bank {

DepositAccount account = new DepositAccount();

ScannerClass scanner = new ScannerClass();
DateManager dateManager = new DateManager();
List<Transaction> transactionsToAdd = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
Writer writer = new Writer();
Reader reader = new Reader();

public void ManageAccount(String name) {
    
    
    
    try {
        File myObj = new File(name + ".txt");

        if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
            File myTransactionObj = new File(name + "Transactions.txt");
            myTransactionObj.createNewFile();
            // If File doesn't exist creates name.txt with 0 balance
            writer.SingleLineWriter(name, "0");
        } else {
            account.setName(name);
            String line = reader.SingleLineRead(name);

            double balance = Double.parseDouble(line);
            double newBalance = ManageBank(balance);

            writer.BalanceAppender(newBalance, name);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void ManageAccountSavings(String name) {

    try {
        File myObj = new File(name + "-Savings.txt");

        if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
            File myTransactionObj = new File(name + "-Savings.Transactions.txt");
            myTransactionObj.createNewFile();
            // If File doesn't exist creates name.txt with 0 balance
            writer.SingleLineWriter(name, "0");
        } else {
            account.setName(name);
            String line = reader.SingleLineRead(name);

            double balance = Double.parseDouble(line);
            double newBalance = ManageBank(balance);

            writer.BalanceAppender(newBalance, name);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public double ManageBank(double balance) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean quit = false;

    List<String> transactions = reader.readPreviousTransactions(account.getName());
    do {

        int userChoice = scanner.InitialChoiceScanner();
        
        

        switch (userChoice) {

        case 1:
            double amount = scanner.DepositScanner();
            
            
            
            balance = account.Deposit(balance, amount);
            System.out.print("Your new balance is: " + balance);

            String depositFullDate = dateManager.getDateAsString();
            Transaction depositTransaction = new Transaction("Deposit", amount, depositFullDate);
            transactionsToAdd.add(depositTransaction);

            break;

        case 2:

            double withdrawAmount = scanner.WithdrawScanner();

            if (withdrawAmount > balance) {
                System.out.println("Sorry not enough funds");
                break;
            }
            balance = account.Withdraw(balance, withdrawAmount);

            System.out.print("Your new balance is: " + balance);

            String withdrawFullDate = dateManager.getDateAsString();
            Transaction withdrawTransaction = new Transaction("Withdraw", withdrawAmount, withdrawFullDate);

            transactionsToAdd.add(withdrawTransaction);

            break;

        case 3:

            System.out.print("Your current balance is: " + balance);

            break;

        case 4:

            writer.displayStatement(account.getName());

            break;

        case 0:

            quit = true;

            break;

        default:

            System.out.println("Please select a valid choice;");

            break;

        }

        System.out.println();

    } while (!quit);

    String name = account.getName();

    List<Transaction> parsedTransactions = writer.parseStringToTransaction(transactions);

    for (Transaction transaction : parsedTransactions) {
        transactionsToAdd.add(transaction);
    }
    writer.transactionWriter(transactionsToAdd, name);

    System.out.println("Thankyou for using the banking service!");

    return balance;
    
}
```

Comment: You may be interested in the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming))

Comment: Oooh thank you I'd never heard of these. So effectively I have an initial method then that  can return either a deposit account object/ savings account object both called account with a simple if statement then?

Comment: At a (very) high level, yes. The important thing is that for this to work you'll need a base `Account` class (maybe make it `abstract` or an interface) that will be extended by `SavingsAccount` and `CheckingAccount`. That method will need to return an `Account`. Maybe look for Java-specific examples of the factory pattern around the web to better see what I mean.

Comment: Perfect thank you, I have an abstract class that they both extend with all my methods in. As it stands both my `SavingsAccount` and `CheckingAccount` class have no code in them they just extend my abstract class and implement an interface I have. Can I just create this method without doing anything else?

Comment: From how you described it, yes, you're basically done :) But if they don't override any method from the parent class, why are they different classes? If they don't have custom behavior it would be simpler to just have a single `Account` class with a field (maybe an enum?) that tells you whether it's a checking or saving account. (Unless, that is, this is homework and you've been explicitly instructed to make subclasses)

Comment: Yeah you're right it's just for a project I'm just following instructions. I think later down the line they have different behaviours you're right. The step that I'm trying to follow is this "Change the main program so that it reads <username>-d.txt into a DepositAccount <username>-s.txt into a SavingsAccount when the program starts". 
<username>-s.txt into a SavingsAccount when the program starts. So thats why I was wondering if you can write some code that returns a different object and changes the method only slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to make you Account as interface with methods those you want,  and have two implementations for your Deposit and Savings accounts..
For example..

```
interface Account {
    void setName(String name);
    String getName();
    void deposit(Double amount);
    void updateBalance(Double balance);
    Double getBalance();
}

class Deposit implements Account {

    private String name;
    private Double balance;

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void deposit(Double amount) {
        this.balance += amount;
    }

    @Override
    public Double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBalance(Double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this currently, for methods in my other classes it requires an account object. These methods will do different things based on what account object is passed in. How would I specify which object to use without just repeating my methods and having 2 of everything, one with `SavingsAccount` and one with a `DepositAccount` ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting the issue completely..
Is it possible to share some example scenario..?

Comment: I can edit some more onto my original post in a second. But you see the `account` object instantiated on the original post is just `Account`. I need to split `Account` into two types of objects `SavingsAccount` and `DepositAccount`. So that method uses my original `Account` object and calls it `account`. Rather than duplicating every method and changing `account` to `depositAccount` and `savingsAccount` I was wondering if it's possible to write some code before my application is run that will declare the object initially. So something like `SavingsAccount account = new SavingsAccount`.